# Casting an JPEG image to CAF receiver app

Tags: chromecast

I've been struggling to send a simple image to a generic, unmodified, by the book, custom CAF receiver app (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_basic)

Tried to send it as a Generic media, with different metadataType's, different media type's... with no success.

Either I get an error '`[cast.framework.PlayerManager] Load failed: Cannot read property 'tracks' of null`' or '`[cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error: Error`'

Loading the image with the same code but with the default receiver (receiverApplicationId: chrome.cast.media.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APP_ID) works just fine. Also did not have any trouble casting an MP4 video.

```
var castSession = cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
var mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo(imgUrl, 'image/jpeg');
mediaInfo.metadata = new chrome.cast.media.GenericMediaMetadata();
mediaInfo.metadata.metadataType = chrome.cast.media.MetadataType.PHOTO;
mediaInfo.metadata.type = chrome.cast.media.MetadataType.PHOTO;


var request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
castSession.loadMedia(request).then(
    function() { console.log('Load succeed'); },
    function(errorCode) { console.log('Error code: ' + errorCode); }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (just got this working, so if you're still looking it might help):

```
var castSession = cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
var mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo(imgUrl, 'image/jpeg');
var metadata = new chrome.cast.media.PhotoMediaMetadata();
metadata.title = "Title text";
metadata.metadataType = chrome.cast.media.MetadataType.PHOTO;
mediaInfo.metadata = metadata;        
var request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
castSession.loadMedia(request).then(
    function() { console.log('Load succeed'); },
    function(errorCode) { console.log('Error code: ' + errorCode); }
);
```